# Post a link with more than 140 characters to twitter using twitter api in Java

Tags: java, twitter

I'm trying to post all status text from our application to twitter, status text can also contains links (of any length) but twitter takes only 140 characters, in the process I saw https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tco-url-wrapper/how-twitter-wrap-urls which shortens all links to around 19 characters, but not sure on how to use this - any blogs/examples would greatly help me.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go - [BitlyJ](http://code.google.com/p/bitlyj/).